# How to Make autoLayout for UISearchController when rotate the device?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a UISearchController integrate with my tableview. For making my searchBar not scrolling with the table, I already made a View (name SearchBarView) under the navigation bar and my table is under this view. All element on my view is setting up using auto layout:
[image]

In my code. I make a UISearchController like a subview of SearchBarView and using sideToFit function for auto fit the width of the screen like this:

```
      self.resultSeachController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

//            add searchbar in the searchbarView
            self.searchBarView.addSubview(controller.searchBar)
            return controller
        })()
```

My SearchBar is working perfect now except one: when I rotate the simulator, the searchBar is not automatic fit the width of screen. It only fit the screen when I touch the SearchBar for searching something.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know how to fix. I tried this code :

```
    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        self.resultSeachController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    }
```

But It's still not working. How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you find any workaround for it ?

Answer (score 4):

Do it while animating along with the transition:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It's so simple! Thank you!

Comment: An alternative is: `_searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width = size.width`